# How to pass a symbol as an argument in switch instruction?

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm still learning matlab and today just for practice I decide to write a function with variable number of arguments, which will do operations like +, * on those arguments. I have question:

- Is there any way to pass a symbol as an argument of this function?

  For example: function(+,a,b,3)

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't believe so, but maybe if you provide an example of what you're actually trying to do we can help determine a suitable alternative

Comment: You can either pass a character, or a function handle. It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As @beaker already said, you can either pass string (char array), or function. The variable number of arguments you can handle using varargin/nargin. See example.

```
function [result] = myfunc(op, varargin) 
    if strcmp(class(op), 'function_handle')
        result = op([varargin{:}]);
        return;
    end

    switch(op)
        case '+'
            result = sum([varargin{:}]);

        case '*' 
            result = prod([varargin{:}]);

        otherwise
            error('unexpected input');
    end
end



>> myfunc(@sum, 1, 2, 3, 4)
ans =
    10

>> myfunc('+', 1, 2, 3, 4)
ans =
    10
```